# Highlight subgraph using Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica

Using Wolfram Mathematica 10.0 I'm trying to highlight a subgraph from the whole graph. As can see at the figure, I succeeded to highlight the subgraph and color the nodes and the edges in a specific color (green). 
I want that the subgraph will be on the top, such that it will be convenient to see the subgraph edges and nodes.

Anyone know how to do that?

[image: Highlight subgraph]

Answer (score 2):

If you used `HighlightGraph`, you can reorder the vertices of the graph to define the rendering order. Do it manually, or use `IGReorderVertices` from the IGraph/M package.

Alternatively, check the "Rendering Order" section of the `GraphLayout` documentation page—it shows how to define the rendering order without changing the order of the vertex list.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently can do that in an easy way, using "Show":
Show[original graph, subgraph].